# How to display date in a different format in oracle

Tags: oracle, date

I have a table with a date field. By default, `select max(date) from table;` returns the date in 'dd-mmm-yy' format. How do I select the date in 'MM/DD/YYYY' format, without changing the table 's structure or the field's format.

Thanks,
Supraja

Comment: Correction: `SELECT MAX(date) FROM table` does *not* return a date in any particular format - `MAX(date)` returns a date, not a string; the format is applied by the client, e.g. in SQL*Plus you could set `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to change the default date display format.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
select to_char(max(date), 'MM/DD/YYYY') from table;
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
select to_char(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy') as maxdate from dual;
```

Some information on the oracle-specific function to_char():

- http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php

Answer (score 2):

Check out the to_char function and the date/time formats it accepts.

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

Exists a table or view v$nls_parameters search here the parameter 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT', this is perfect for not be changing the format each while.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM v$nls_parameters WHERE UPPER(PARAMETER) = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYYMMDD';
```

There is also the possibility from make for register of win. in tree

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home9
```

Here key NLS_DATE_FORMAT, change for your format date.

Comment: You can also change `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` through the UI:

Tools>Preferences>Database>NLS>Date Format