# ALTER SESSION over Ms Access Passtrough for Oracle

Tags: sql, vba, oracle, ms-access

i need to execute this command, which works perfectly if I execute it via ADODB

```
ADOConn.Execute ("ALTER session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT=""DD.MM.YYYY"" ")
```

Since I need to join multiple databases from different systems, I switched to passtrough queries to join them later. Now I need to change the date format via my passtrough query, but this just does not want to work.

```
ALTER session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT="DD.MM.YYYY"
```

I execute this command before my select command.
I get this error:

```
ODBC--call failed.
[ORACLE][ODBC][ORA]ORA-00922: missing or invalid option (#922)
```

What am I missing? I tried to mess around with the quotation marks but could not success.

Comment: Have you set the returns records property to false on the pass through query?

Comment: Consider avoiding session variables and use [`to_char`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202828/how-to-display-date-in-a-different-format-in-oracle) to handle date display: `select to_char(sysdate,'DD.MM.YYYY') as maxdate from dual;`

Answer (score 1):

Well, such commands are only  going to apply to the given connection.

So you have this:

```
ALTER session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT="DD.MM.YYYY";
SELECT * from tblHotels;
```

Note how we have two command statments in the one Pass-though query. I am assuming that you are doing the same thing? And test + try using the Oracle console, since if the raw sql you are sending does not work on/from the oracle console, then it certainly will not work as per above. So, you can (and should) include the multiple commands in the ONE pt query - I used ";" as the command delimiter - but use what ever works for oracle. So, you MUST get your command(s) working in via the oracle console, and then put them all together one after another into the PT query.

If you going to execute the command separate, then as noted then you have to set returns records = false. But as ntoed, setting the session is ONLY going to apply to the one PT query, not every query sent, since you using a new connection and session for each time you execute a PT query. So, you likly have to include the date format command right BEFORE the select command. As noted, you can stack up and include as many commands in the SINGLE PT query. So, simply stack up the "no count" and the severl other commands, and then include your alter sessio, and then finally at the at of the single PT query, include your  select command.